# Obfuscation with Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking into obfuscating my Windows Phone 8 app.

The first thing that's thrown me a little is that most programs I've looked at talk about obfuscating the `.DLL` file that is generated when my build my app, but it's the `.xap` file I upload to the store? So I don't understand what difference obfuscating the `.DLL` files would make?

Comment: Oh, I've just read that the .xap file is essentially a zip file, so renaming it to .zip gives me access to the .DLL files contained within the archive, so I can obfuscate those! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since some time all XAPs are delivered trough secure connection. There is no need for Obfuscation as the XAP file cannot be accessed on the device or while downloading.

Comment: Do you really trust this solution? Think about jailbreak or other developer tools, I would not be so confident.

Comment: All marketplace XAPs are signed with Microsofts DRM technology. You can't unpack it. I am not concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone store itself encrypts the XAP, so nobody can decrypt it. When any one installs the app, the DLLs & other files are not accessible via SD card or file manager. If anybody downloads XAP from app store via "Download and install manually" & try to rename .XAP to .ZIP then it won't work.

If you want to try, download XAP from [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/turn-me-off/df8fc2b2-1d9c-45fe-b844-9ec4118fe705/xap?apptype=regular) & try to rename & extract source from it, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: I appreciate your answers, both Xyroid and Andras, so my question then would be why does there appear to be such a big market for Obfuscation software?

Comment: Check out: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/129296/the-case-for-code-obfuscation

Answer (score 1):

I understand peoples trepidation around the security of being able to extract the dlls from a store .xap file, especially if someone cracks it at some point in the future. My boss is one of them, so I was asked to obfuscate my Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight app before committing it to the store.

I looked at a few, and recommend ConfuserEx. By setting a few simple settings, I was able to completely mangle the code, method names, constants and everything else. Reflector couldn't even open the dlls and ILSPY just showed a whole load of full-stops. Very impressed - it even did this to the main UI project as well.

Its a bit of trial and error, but just set a global policy with Protection=None, then add in "invalid metadata" protection (i also added "constants" and "rename" to all except the main UI project).

And its free!!!

Not impenetrable I know, but does add that little bit more protection (as they say, "keeps honest people honest"). Its also useful to do as a post-build event, especially if you're passing your xap file direct to stakeholders for evaluation without going through the store.