# Securely save default application settings in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, settings

I have some sensitive information like `application_key` and `connection_string`. They must be predefined for users who install the application. Is it possible to set them so that noone can disassemble XAP file to see the actual values (for example in windows we can encrypt configuration file sections)?
Im not talking about user-entered data that can be encrypted(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487164(v=vs.105).aspx), im talking about data, avaliable from application load; for example `application_key` that is needed to connect to some server and gain access to some actions; so that i don't want such things to be visible.

**Update**: think ive found the solution:
 [Obfuscation with Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683645/obfuscation-with-windows-phone-8) so that XAP from the store CANT be opened and thats it!

Comment: One solution is to have your keys stored in a Runtime (c++) dll. No way to decompile c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the UPDATE. The XAP from the store, even downloaded, can not be opened, its obfuscated by default.